# How to add pdf file to django response

Tags: python, django

I have a model that contains a link to the file stored in AWS S3.

```
class Documents(models.Model):
    """ uploaded documents"""

    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    filedata = models.FileField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage())
    filename = models.CharField(_('documents name'), max_length=64)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    filetype = models.ForeignKey(Doctype, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    url_link = models.URLField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

**url_link** is the field using pre-signed URLs from boto3 for to get access to privat S3 repo.
I'm trying to make a function that receives the model's id, loads it by reference and passes it to response for further processing in the SPA.
Based on the answers found on the stackoverflow, I wrote the following function

```
def view_pdf(request, pk):
    pdf = get_object_or_404(Documents, pk=pk)
    response = requests.get(pdf.url_link)
    with open(response, 'rb') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), mimetype='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=some_file.pdf'
        return response
    pdf.closed
```

BUt got an error

```
TypeError at /api/v1/files/pdf/90
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Response
```

**error traceback**

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/files/pdf/90
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/y700/projects/healthline/lifeline-backend/apps/files/views.py", line 68, in view_pdf
    with open(response, 'rb') as pdf:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Response
HTTP GET /api/v1/files/pdf/90 500 [1.06, 127.0.0.1:57280]
```

Comment: Could you post the error's traceback?

Comment: Your main problem (the traceback) is that you try to somehow read a response that you get from requests like `open(response, 'rb')`. I do not know as to why you do that. That's why the error clearly says it expected `str`, `bytes` or a file object while you give it a `Response` object.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I got FileNotFoundError error

Comment: @ErdinEray I do this in order to transfer the open file to the React app, which will offer options for saving the file. React cannot access the closed repository, so I have to do it with the backend

Comment: @Jekson You don't need to use the `with open(response, 'rb') as pdf:`. You can set the `HttpResponse` directly from the `response.content` . ie, `response = HttpResponse(response.content, mimetype='application/pdf')`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Your solution works, but instead of `mimetype`  have to write `content_type`. Thanks!

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM you should repost your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it and other peoples having the same issue can find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response = requests.get(pdf.url_link)
```

Here `response` is a [`Response`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/428f7a275914f60a8f1e76a7d69516d617433d30/requests/models.py#L587) class object, which contains a server's response to an HTTP request. In order to access the `response` body as `bytes`(for non-text requests) you should use [`response.content`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) [attribute](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/428f7a275914f60a8f1e76a7d69516d617433d30/requests/models.py#L830). ie,

```
response = HttpResponse(response.content, content_type='application/pdf')
```